# How to improve items representation with Canvas and ItemsControl WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas, itemscontrol

Hi I have to represent a bunch of elements (about 1000). These elements have a public property like this.

```
public Point DeviceImagePosition
{
        get
        {
            return deviceImagePosition;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != deviceImagePosition)
            {
                deviceImagePosition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(PROPERTY_NAME_DEVICE_IMAGE_POSITION);
            }
        }
}
```

This Property is updated every second. I am using a Task to calculate the new item position so it out of the UI thread. On the UIThread I only set the new Point to DeviceImagePosition.

The ItemsControl I'm using is like this.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrackRendererList}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Canvas />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"      Value="{Binding Path=DeviceImagePosition.X}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=DeviceImagePosition.Y}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-5" 
                                                                         Stroke="Red" Fill="Red"

                                                                         StrokeThickness="1" 
                                                                         Opacity="0.5">

                                        </Ellipse>
                                    </DataTemplate>

                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
```

I have really poor performance, The app seems almost frozen.. 
Any ideas to improve performance????

Comment: You could try virtualization techniques with scroll then, but if they need to visible at one glance then you need to implement throttled loading, by making sure not more then N items are added to bound collection asynchronously, to allow UI thread to paint them fast enough

Comment: As a note, setting `Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-5"` on the Ellipse in the DataTemplate has no effect, because the Canvas is not the direct parent of the Ellipse. You may use a Path with an EllipseGeometry instead.

Comment: On my system I get a slightly better performance when I replace the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` bindings by a `RenderTransform` with a `TranslateTransform` with bound `X` and `Y` values.